# Movie about a soccer team travelling in a van discovering aliens disguised as humans

Tags: story-identification, movie

A time ago I watched a low-budget movie on YouTube about a high school American soccer team who were traveling in a city using a van at night. They were travelling to play with another team. A some point the van broke down, and a student tried to repair it.  (I remember something about the carburetor.)  He was not successful,  and the team found a storage occupied by aliens disguised like humans. I remember they talked to each other about how dangerous the neighborhood was when they were walking.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this?  (How long ago was it?)

Comment: I saw in YouTube kind of 5 years ago, but the movie look like was in the 80's or maybe in the early 90's. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

[Star Hunter (1996)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114529/?ref_=tt_urv)

> Star hunters are the space monsters who hunt helpless creatures for pleasure. One night couple of high school football players and their cheerleaders are returning home after the lost game. But, when their bus makes the wrong turn, they are going to meet those creatures, and the real game will begin.

Comment: Hello: amazing, this is the movie...thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome!