# movie about vampire and a hunter

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, vampire

I recall seeing a movie on VHS from Blockbuster many years ago. It was about a vampire and a hunter, and there was also a young girl involved (perhaps because she fell in love with the vampire). In addition, the movie depicted a really "dark scenes", I remembered the movie was very dark ambient.
The only thing I can recall is a scene in the middle of the film where the hunter and the girl had a dinner reservation in a restaurant. They talked in a very ominous tone, and while the hunter may have eaten something light, the girl received a plate of something horrifying, making her nervous. The hunter then said something along the lines of, "Enjoy your food." The plate was something similar a "burnt bird" or similar..

If anyone could help me to remembered the movie name, I would be grateful.

Thank You

Comment: Reminder to accept your answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266321/movie-about-a-soccer-team-travelling-in-a-van-discovering-aliens-disguised-as-hu (which you accepted in a comment) by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, in which time period was the story set in?

Comment: Hello: indistinctly maybe in 1998,1999,2000, around this years when VHS was popular at blockbuster.

Comment: If the vampires can only be killed by having their necks broken, the 1998 *[Night Hunter](https://youtu.be/K7c2QeU2j0U)* ticks at least some of the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently watching through it on Tubi, but the 1996 *[Night Hunter](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/NightHunter1996)* starring Don "the Dragon" Wilson might be your film.

> Jack Cutter is a vampire hunter. Skilled in many forms of combat, he is a bane to creatures of the night the world over. There's just one problem: He's the Last of His Kind, and the undead outnumber him significantly. After he kills a few bloodsuckers in LA, he's on the run from the police and other vamps. Can he survive when he's outmanned and outgunned?

Unfortunately, I haven't found the restaurant scene you mention just yet.

Comment: Hello: Unfortunately,  I check the movie that you are mentioning and is not the correct....thank you for your effort....I would try to add  more information if I can remember more details...

Comment: @BobLin: I actually did get a chance to watch the film through, and indeed, not a match. But then I had to run off to work, so I didn't get a chance to amend the answer. Best of luck!